# Is @IBAction just a syntax in Swift or does @Something mean a particular thing in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, ibaction

Is @IBAction just a syntactical difference in Swift or does it signify something specific.
Also, similar usage is seen in AppDelegate.swift where @UIApplicationMain is written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are `attributes` in swift.They have some special meaning for compiler.For eg: `@UIApplicationMain` synthesize `main.swift` file by compiler as entry point for application.From swift [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Attributes.html)

> Attributes provide more information about a declaration or type.
>   There are two kinds of attributes in Swift, those that apply to
>   declarations and those that apply to types.
>
> **NSApplicationMain**
>        Apply this attribute to a class to indicate that it is the application delegate. Using this attribute is equivalent to calling
>   the NSApplicationMain function and passing this class’s name as the
>   name of the delegate class.
>
> If you do not use this attribute, supply a main.swift file with a main
>   function that calls the NSApplicationMain function. For example, if
>   your app uses a custom subclass of NSApplication as its principle 
>   class, call the NSApplicationMain function instead of using this
>   attrib

[Here is whole list of attributes in swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_543)

From apple swift [blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7)

> In Xcode, Mac templates default to including a “main.swift” file, but
>   for iOS apps the default for new iOS project templates is to add
>   @UIApplicationMain to a regular Swift file. This causes the compiler
>   to synthesize a main entry point for your iOS app, and eliminates the
>   need for a “main.swift” file.
>
> Alternatively, you can link in an implementation of main written in
>   Objective-C, common when incrementally migrating projects from
>   Objective-C to Swift.

write code in `main.swift`.It will work as enty point for application

```
//main.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV,nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

Comment: "If you do not use this attribute, supply a main.swift file with a main function that calls the NSApplicationMain function. For example, if your app uses a custom subclass of NSApplication as its principle class, call the NSApplicationMain function instead of using this attrib" How do I do that in the main.swift?

Comment: create main.swift and write main function.Swift application looks if main.swift is present or not.If present calls main function.

Comment: NSApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV)
thats how it is right now